# How to show that a function : Z = aXn+bY m is an unbiased estimator of µ for any constants a,b that satisfy a + b = 1.

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n,Y_1,\dots,Y_m$ be i.i.d. random variables, each with mean $\mu$ and finite variance $σ^2 > 0$.
 Let $X_n$ and $Y_m$ denote the sample means of $\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$ and $\{Y_1,\dots,Y_m\}$ respectively.

1. Show that $Z = aX_n+bY_m$ is an unbiased estimator of $\mu$ for any constants $a,b$ that satisfy $a + b = 1$.
2. In this case when $a + b = 1$, determine the values of $a,b$ that minimize $\operatorname{Var}(Z)$.

For part 1, I solved it by simply applying the theory that expectation is linear and solved it accordingly. 
For part 2, I am stuck with it from the get-go.

Comment: If you go and accept some of the answers to questions you've already posted, maybe someone will be kind enough to help you with your math stats homework.

Comment: thanks @Renard . Am still on my way to figuring out how this site works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X_n,\,Y_m$ are independent, 
$$\operatorname{Var}Z=\operatorname{Var}(aX_n +bY_m)=a^2\operatorname{Var}X_n +b^2\operatorname{Var}X_m =(a^2+b^2)\sigma^2,$$
which is minimal for $a=b=1/2$.

Comment: I did get till (2+2)2, but in my thought process but may I know ur thought process behind a=b=1/2 , which will give Var(Z) =^2/4 ? I am not able to get the connection.

Comment: Hint: $a^2+b^2=a^2+(1-a)^2$.